# Chinese Remainder Theorem for integral ring homomorphisms

Tags: commutative-algebra, solution-verification, maximal-and-prime-ideals, localization, chinese-remainder-theorem

Let $A\to B$ be an integral homomorphism of commutative rings, $\mathfrak p\subseteq A$ be a prime ideal and $\mathscr Q$ be a finite set of prime ideals of $B$ lying above $\mathfrak p$.
I ask if the canonical ring homomorphism
$$B\to\prod_{\mathfrak q\in\mathscr Q}B/\mathfrak q$$
is surjective.

*My attempt:* By localizing at $\mathfrak p$ we get the ring homomorphism
$$B_{\mathfrak p}\to\prod_{\mathfrak q\in\mathscr Q}B_{\mathfrak p}/\mathfrak qB_{\mathfrak p}$$
which is surjective because $\mathfrak qB_{\mathfrak p}$ are distinct maximal ideals of $B_{\mathfrak p}$ since they lies above the maximal ideal $\mathfrak pA_{\mathfrak p}$ of $A_{\mathfrak p}$.

For every prime $\mathfrak p'\neq\mathfrak p$ of $A$, the ring homomorphism
$$B_{\mathfrak p'}\to\prod_{\mathfrak q\in\mathscr Q}B_{\mathfrak p'}/\mathfrak qB_{\mathfrak p'}$$
is surjective as well, because $\mathfrak qB_{\mathfrak p'}=B_{\mathfrak p'}$, hence the right-handed side is zero.

Since being surjective for an $A$-module homomorphism is a local property, the assertion is proved.

Question. Is the statement true and this approach correct?

Comment: Try the following example. $k[u,v]\subset k[x,y]$ with $u\mapsto x^2, v\mapsto y^2$. Take the prime ideal generated by $u-v$ and assume characteristics is not two.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is in the paragraph:

> For every prime $\mathfrak p'\neq\mathfrak p$ of $A$, the ring homomorphism
> $$B_{\mathfrak p'}\to\prod_{\mathfrak q\in\mathscr Q}B_{\mathfrak p'}/\mathfrak qB_{\mathfrak p'}$$
> is surjective as well, because $\mathfrak qB_{\mathfrak p'}=B_{\mathfrak p'}$, hence the right-handed side is zero.

beacuse, in general, $\mathfrak p'\neq\mathfrak p$ doesn't implies $\mathfrak qB_{\mathfrak p'}=B_{\mathfrak p'}$, for example, when $\mathfrak p'\supset\mathfrak p$.